# Klarna checkout HTTP ERROR 405 in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, klarna

I am using Klarna checkout, and getting this type of error on front-end  **HTTP ERROR 405**.

I am using **klarna/module-kco** module (installed module via composer) in magento 2.3.1, added test credential in back-end and enabled **Klarna Checkout**.

In front-end flow added product in cart and checkout,
showing klarna payment form , so filled that form, when i submit that form 
that time giving error "HTTP ERROR 405".

Any help appreciated!

Thanks, 
[image]

Comment: can u please Screenshot of error message in your question

Comment: @WaqarAli added image please check description

Comment: please Add Console result

Answer (score 0):

I am getting below error in the Magento log file after adding Playground credential.

> [2021-03-18 12:55:09] klarnaDebugLogger.ERROR: Bad Response: Client error: POST https://api-na.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions r> { "error_code" : "INVALID_OPERATION", "error_messages" : [ "" ], "correlation_id" : "efdf0a6c-ebca-4c8f-a7a3-dba93 (truncated...)